# What is wrong with my poem?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

Poetry seemed too difficult this time
Tough... I couldn't find many rhymes
Ideas... just words, a literary crime.

**This poem doesn't feel right - what exactly is wrong with it?**

**CLUE 1**

> Since poetry is fairly freeform and rule-free, for there to be something wrong I must have been trying to do something specific.

**CLUE 2**

> If you work out what I was *trying* to do with this poem and apply it then not only will you get the answer to "what is wrong" but you will also find the poem makes sense!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems to me that at first you wanted:

> to write a haiku

but then

> You also wanted it to rhyme, which ruined it

Explanation:

> By removing the ending rhyming phrases from each line we get:
> **Poetry seemed too**  <s>difficult this time</s> 
> **Tough...I couldn't find many**  <s>rhymes</s>
> **Ideas... just words**        <s>a literary crime</s>
> Which is a perfectly good haiku

EDIT AFTER HINTS:
As for what *exactly* is wrong with the poem:

> The last word of each truncated line combine to say "Too many words" which is the problem with this 'haiku'

Comment: Well done! This is *almost* completely correct. You're just missing the answer to "what is wrong with it" - and it is staring you in the face!

Comment: @Astralbee Are you looking for something more than ROT13(Gur unvxh unf gur jebat ahzore bs flyynoyrf, naq qbrfa'g arrq gb eulzr) or does that cover it?

Comment: Not quite... ROT13(Lbh ner pbeerpg gung Unvxhf qb abg hfhnyyl eulzr, naq bapr lbh nccyl gur ehyrf bs n Unvxh (gung V vtaberq) gur cbrz ab ybatre eulzrf. Qb lbh abgvpr nalguvat ryfr nobhg gur yvarf lbh gehapngrq?)

Comment: I can't really post this as a separate answer since TwoBitOperation has done all the work, but is the final answer of what's wrong with it simply that rot13(vg qbrfa'g eulzr, ohg gung'f jung lbh frg bhg gb qb)

Comment: I'd love to mark this as the correct answer, I'd just like to see it completed. ROT13(Abj lbh unir gehapngrq gur cbrz gb zrrg gur 5-7-5 ehyr bs n Unvxh, qb lbh abgvpr nalguvat nobhg gur jbeqf gung rnpu yvar abj raqf ba?)

Comment: Got it.  Sorry I needed such a large poke to see it!

Answer (score 2):

The amounts of words in each sentence spell out

> 666

Comment: I think there might be more to the answer than just this, but it ain't my riddle, so I don't know. Nice observation, though! $(+1)$ :P

Comment: Interesting observation but not intentional and doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: (And wasn't true for the original incarnation of this puzzle anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

> those are not ellipses. It is missing 3 letter words "how" and "are"

in

> Poetry seemed too difficult this time 
> Tough **how** I couldn't find many rhymes 
> Ideas **are** just words, a literary crime.

Comment: That's just a bit of poetic license. Not the answer i was looking for in afraid.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with so far was that

> the syllables follow a 10-8-10 pattern.

After additional research, I found

> this site: http://poetscollective.org/poetryforms/tag/8-or-10-syllables/

It looks as though you were

> trying to form a RenRhyme, but had already violated the rule mixing 8's and 10's.

Comment: Interesting. I have never heard of a RenRhyme! But you are thinking along the right lines.

Answer (score 0):

> This poem doesn't feel right - what exactly is wrong with it?

It's totally a gamble but from looking at @TwoBitOperation's answer I noticed that:

> After he arranged the poem so that you will be  good haiku,From the words he downloaded, one can create a kind of sentence: **difficult ,this time rhymes -a literary crime**-This means that what causes the poem to be a literary crime is the rhymes

So if the question what were wrong?the answer is:

> the rhymes

Comment: You're thinking along the right lines but kind of back to front. You're looking for an answer in the words that need taking away...

Answer (score 0):

According to @TwoBitOperation’s answer

“It seems to me that at first you wanted:

> to write a haiku

but then

> You also wanted it to rhyme, which ruined it

Explanation:

> By removing the ending rhyming phrases from each line we get:
> **Poetry seemed too**  <s>difficult this time</s> 
> **Tough...I couldn't find many**  <s>rhymes</s>
> **Ideas... just words**        <s>a literary crime</s>*
> Which is a perfectly good haiku.

“

The words in the haiku make the sentence

> Poetry seemed too tough... I couldn’t find many ideas... just words

Which is what is wrong with your poem.

Answer (score 0):

(@TwoBitOperation has done 99% of it, so if this is right I'm happy enough for them to edit it in to their answer and take the tick)

What's wrong with your poem is that

> it's not a rhyming haiku

which is what you were "trying" to create

As @TwoBitOperation pointed out

> it's not a haiku as the syllable count was thrown out by adding the rhyming bits. But removing those to make it a haiku means it no longer rhymes.

Answer (score 0):

Three lines.

> It's probably a Haiku. So, you just need to make some changes.

Poetry seemed too difficult this time

> Then use the shortest, and one without a need for a rhyme. A haiku.

Tough... I couldn't find many rhymes

> Haikus don't need rhymes, so it's good for this.

Ideas... just words, a literary crime.

> Too many words, just take some away.

So, here's my revision of the poem:

> Poetry is hard
>  I cannot find any rhymes
>  A poetic crime.